# Why sibbling div elements are rendered as children of one of them

Tags: css, html, html-rendering

For some reason div elements change their parents during rendering in unexpected way, reproducible in Firefox and Chrome.

E.g.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="slot"/>
    <div class="slot"/>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Firefox debugger will show as this at runtime as:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="slot"><div class="slot"/></div></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

When I remove .slot elements(see the code attached), everything renders as expected(#footer place in tree after rendering is same as in the source).

Code:
http://pastebin.com/3j3aQFdh

Comment: Works as intended for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/FPd2H/

Comment: From the looks of http://pastebin.com/3j3aQFdh, you're not closing off the <div class="slots"> elements.

Comment: yeah, div's not closed, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use empty divs: like that

```
<div />
```

You should try to change your code to use valid divs with empty content:

```
<div></div>
```

Comment: Why is this?  Aren't the two supposed to be equivalent?

Comment: No, in both XML and HTML the tag without the body and the tag with empty body are different. This is somewhat similar to the NULL versus the empty string.